# efficient dplyr summarise in one data frame based on intervals in another one

Tags: r, dplyr

I frequently need to calculate means of many parameters in time series datasets based on intervals defined as "events" in a second dataset.

The example code below illustrates my current approach, which does work nicely.

As my datasets will be increasing, though, I am wondering if there is a more efficient way (example runs in ~30 s on my PC).

It is important to stay within dplyr/tidyverse (data.table ways are appreciated, but won't really help).

```
  library(tidyverse)

  #generate time series data
  data <- bind_cols(
    data_frame(td=seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-01-01 00:00"), 
                                 to = as.POSIXct("2010-12-31 23:59"), 
                                 by = 60)),
  as_data_frame(replicate(20,runif(525600))))

  #generate events
  events <- data_frame(
  event = as.character(1:669),
  start_cet = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-01-01 00:00"),
          to = as.POSIXct("2010-12-01 00:00"),
          by = 43200),
  stop_cet = seq(from = as.POSIXct("2010-01-01 02:00"),
           to = as.POSIXct("2010-12-01 02:00"),
           by = 43200)
  )

  #calculate means of data columns within event intervals
  system.time(
  means <- events %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(s = list(data %>% select(td) %>% filter(td >= start_cet & td < stop_cet))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(event,td) %>%
  left_join(.,data) %>%
  group_by(event) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(V1:V20),funs(mean=mean)) %>%
  ungroup()
  )
```

Comment: Why is it "important to stay within package XYZ" for you?

Comment: FWIW, It seems almost all the function time is consumed in the `mutate` step.

Comment: There **is** a much more efficient way that runs instantaneously for your example, but it won't stay within your arbitrary constraints. You want to dig a hole using a hammer instead of a shovel. Good luck with that.

Comment: I don't really like mixing packages with different philosophies and data formats within one data processing chain. It has caused me quite some headache in the past, especially when I go back to older sripts after a while. I would be interested in your data.table solution anyway. Maybe I will need to move in the future with even larger datasets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an efficient way of doing it using the [latest devel](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation) (1.9.7+) version of `data.table` that takes about 10 milliseconds to run for OP sample:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data); setDT(events)

data[events, on = .(td >= start_cet, td <= stop_cet), lapply(.SD, mean), by = .EACHI]
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer to myself after ~ 3 yrs...

The `mutate` step in the above dplyr solution was unnecessarily complicated, as also indicated in the comment by JDLong. I now use

```
means2 <- events %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(td = list(seq(start_cet, stop_cet - 60, "min"))) %>%
  unnest() %>%
  select(event,td) %>%
  left_join(.,data) %>%
  group_by(event) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(V1:V20),funs(mean=mean)) %>%
  ungroup()
```

which is ~ 25 times faster than the old `dplyr` solution above.

The `dt` solution is still ~ 5 times faster than this `dplyr` chain. However, the output is a bit messed up. Instead of a column with the events, I get two columns `td`, which are the start and stop times of the events. Some `dt` experts know how to fix this?